# calculate properties values depending on another property (LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class with properties: `Row, Seat`.
For example we have the following data:

```
Row Seat
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    4
2    5
```

I want return `Dictionary<int,int>` that contain `Row` as key, and numbers of seats in row as value.
For above example the dictionary will contain two records:

```
Key Value
1    3
2    2
```

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: did you mean the **maximum** number of seats in a row to be returned as value?

Comment: Use GroupBy() and Count() like you would do in SQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.Row)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

Comment: Without the `.ToArray()`. The OP wants to have a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: @user348173: You should measure the performance yourself to see if it fast enough for your requirements. Tip: Look at the produced SQL using the SQL Profiler to see if it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: If `list` is an `IQueryable<T>`, you might gain something by supplying an anonymous type (such as `new { Row = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }`) into the dictionary, since `ToDictionary` will operate on `IEnumerable<T>` and will possibly force you to return much more data from the database than strictly needed.

Answer (score 4):

It's not too involved:

```
var seatings = new List<Seatings>(); /* list of your class instances */
seatings.GroupBy(s => s.Row).ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Count());
```

Grouping by row yields a collection of groups where each group has a `Key` equal to the row and can be enumerated to yield all the seatings in that row. You can make a dictionary directly out of that with `ToDictionary`.